# Given a "frozen" SciPy discrete random variable, how can I know its support?

Tags: python, random, scipy

If I manually create a discrete random variable using `scipy.stats.rv_discrete`, I can control its support (the possible values it can get) either by providing a lower bound, an upper bound and and increment (though the latter was [tested only for 1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html)), or by providing a concrete `values` argument.

The methods does not actually construct a random variable, but instead constructs a discrete *distribution*, from which a random variable can be constructed by calling it. Given a random variable that was constructed from a distribution that was constructed by giving concrete `values=`  that way, I can figure out its support by checking `rv.dist.xk` (in fact, that's not enough; if `values=` contained zero probabilities, we should really check `rv.dist.xk` and `rv.dist.pk` to discard zero probability values from the support). However, such a method won't work for general discrete random variables that we have not defined and that were not defined using the `values=` method.

Is there a general method that can return the support set of a discrete random variable? A **single method** that will work for all discrete random variables that were generated using `rv_discrete` *and* for those defined in the `scipy.stats` module, such as `randint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the lower and upper bound of the support of the distribution from the inverse cdf, `ppf` of the scipy.stats.distribution.

By definition, `ppf(0)` returns the largest integer for which the cdf is zero, so the lower bound is larger by 1.

If I remember correctly, then the code doesn't check whether the user has added zero probability events for a discrete distribution that is explicitly defined by users with `(xk, pk)`.

```
>>> stats.binom.ppf([0, 1], 20, 0.4)
array([ -1.,  20.])

>>> stats.geom.ppf([0, 1], 0.4)
array([  0.,  inf])

>>> stats.hypergeom.ppf([0, 1], 20, 15, 10)
array([  4.,  10.])

>>> stats.bernoulli.ppf([0, 1], 0.5)
array([-1.,  1.])
```

The distributions have a `.a` and a `.b` attribute that defines the lower bound. However, if the support depends on the parameters, it shows **the bounds of the last call** in which it was set. Also these are the bounds for the standard distribution with `loc=0`, and also `scale=1` for continuous distribution.

**Only** use this if you want to get familiar with the details of the implementation, and you don't mind hunting for some difficult to find bugs. It's mostly for internal use.

```
>>> stats.hypergeom.ppf([0, 1], 20, 15, 10)
array([  4.,  10.])
>>> stats.hypergeom.a, stats.hypergeom.b
(5, array(10))

# WRONG, stale state ! 
>>> stats.hypergeom(20, 16, 10).dist.a, stats.hypergeom(20, 16, 10).dist.b   
(5, array(10))

>>> stats.hypergeom(20, 16, 10).ppf(0)
5.0
>>> stats.hypergeom(20, 16, 10).dist.a, stats.hypergeom(20, 16, 10).dist.b
(6, array(10))
```

Comment: They do for all the built-in distributions. If you build your own distribution, then you have to add part of the story yourself. The discrete distribution are on integers, not defined on the real line.

Comment: I understand that; however, my entire question was about a method which answers the question both for built-in distributions **and** for custom-made ones. Look at the emphasized text at the end of my question.

Comment: The only method that works is to add, additionally to the above, a check for all integer points in [a, b] for `pmf(k) > 0`. It's a waste computationally to check this each time a method is used, so it's better to store the support. There is no way to check in general whether there are gaps in the support if the upper bound b is inf. For example, Poisson that is only defined on even numbers, i.e. scale=2. There is no built-in support for distributions like that.

Comment: I see, thanks, that's an answer... I'll have to subclass or contain scipy's random variables if that's the case.

Comment: I'm just checking an example that uses a noninteger `xk`. I'm surprised that it actually seems to be working for pmf, cdf and ppf. I thought this is not allowed, and I don't remember any unit tests for this. I'm puzzled and think that it's not supposed to work correctly.

Comment: That's interesting. If you find anything more about it, please let me know... Thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to look into this right now. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3758 to track this. I would avoid non-integer xk for now.